# vim: execute Vundle install from command line

Tags: vim, vundle

I'm using vim and vundle. One of the steps to setup my vim env is to open vim, and then type `:BundleInstall` or `:PluginInstall`. I am trying to script this setup. Is there a way I can execute this without entering vim interactively itself? Meaning, without opening vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this github issue:

https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/issues/225

it looks like you might be able to run from the command line, or bash script:

```
vim +PluginInstall +qall
```